# Firebase undefined is not an object in React Native

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native

I'm using react-native with firebase

I've installed firebase using

```
npm install firebase --save
```

my app runs, but right when I add

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');
```

in my index.ios.js I get

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n.navigator')
```

and in the xcode output

```
Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module
```

when I remove the line, my app runs again. Is there something I'm missing to be able to run Firebase and react-native together?

Comment: This is a known issue in React Native 0.22.0 and the latest Firebase JavaScript SDK (2.4.1 at the moment). Follow [this Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6566) to know when it is resolved.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That's a very good **answer**.